# SQLException: This ResultSet is closed

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to compare values from three `Resultset`, but there seems to exception wen I try to run it. 
Could someone help me on where am going wrong. I will appreciate any help. Here's the code snippet that's throwing the error:

```
    java.sql.Connection connDB = null;

    java.lang.Object[] reconciledPaymentDetails = null;

    java.util.Vector shiftsVector = new java.util.Vector(1, 1);

    String status = "";

    try {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
    try {
        connDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + hostName + ":" + portNumber 
        + "/" + dbName, userName, password);

       System.out.println("Connection established : [" + connDB.toString() + "]");

       java.sql.Statement pstmt = connDB.createStatement();

       java.sql.Statement pstmtShifts = connDB.createStatement();

       java.sql.ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT payment_mode,  
       transaction_type, credit FROM ac_cash_collection WHERE shift_no = '" + shiftNumber + 
       "'");

    while (rset.next()) {
       java.sql.ResultSet rsetShifts = pstmtShifts.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT amount, 
       shift_amount FROM ac_shift_collections WHERE shift_no = '" + shiftNumber + "' AND 
       pay_mode ilike '"+rset.getString(1) +"'");

          while (rsetShifts.next()) {

            java.sql.ResultSet rset2 = pstmt.executeQuery("select debit from ac_cash_book where 
            shift_no='"+shiftNumber+"'");

               while (rset2.next()){
                   double debit =rset2.getDouble("debit");

                    if((rset2.getDouble("debit")<=0 ))

                       status = "no_banked";

                    else if((rset2.getDouble("debit")==rsetShifts.getDouble("amount")) &&  
                         (rsetShifts.getDouble("amount"))< rsetShifts.getDouble("shift_amount"))

                       status= "BntClosed";

                   else if (rset2.getDouble(1)==rsetShifts.getDouble("shift_amount"))

                       Status ="bClosed";

              shiftsVector.addElement(rset.getString(1)+":"+rsetShifts.getString(1)+":"+status);
    } 
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
java.sql.ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT payment_mode, transaction_type, credit FROM ac_cash_collection WHERE shift_no = '" + shiftNumber + "'");
java.sql.ResultSet rset2 = pstmt.executeQuery("select debit from ac_cash_book where shift_no='"+shiftNumber+"'");
```

Your second call releases the resources generated by the first one, that's why the ResultSet is closed.