# SQLException: This ResultSet is closed when trying to loop through three resultsets

Tags: java, postgresql

m trying to loop through 3 resultsets and compare their values. bt its throwing this exception...could someone help me on where am going through?
here is the piece of code:

java.lang.Object[] reconciledPaymentDetails = null;

```
java.util.Vector shiftsVector = new java.util.Vector(1, 1);

String status = "";

try {

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } 
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
try {
    connDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + hostName + ":" + portNumber + "/" + dbName, userName, password);

    System.out.println("Connection established : [" + connDB.toString() + "]");

    java.sql.Statement pstmt = connDB.createStatement();

    java.sql.Statement pstmtShifts = connDB.createStatement();

    java.sql.ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT payment_mode,transaction_type, credit FROM ac_cash_collection WHERE shift_no = '" + shiftNumber + "'");

    while (rset.next()) {

        java.sql.ResultSet rsetShifts = pstmtShifts.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT amount, shift_amount FROM ac_shift_collections WHERE shift_no = '" + shiftNumber + "' AND pay_mode ilike '"+rset.getString(1) +"'");

        while (rsetShifts.next()) {

            java.sql.ResultSet rset2 = pstmt.executeQuery("select debit from ac_cash_book where shift_no='"+shiftNumber+"'");


           while (rset2.next()){

                double debit =rset2.getDouble("debit");

                if((rset2.getDouble("debit")<=0 ))

             status = "no_banked";

               else if((rset2.getDouble("debit")==rsetShifts.getDouble("amount"))
                        && (rsetShifts.getDouble("amount"))< rsetShifts.getDouble("shift_amount"))
                        status= "BntClosed";
                else if (rset2.getDouble(1)==rsetShifts.getDouble("shift_amount"))
                    status ="bClosed";




            shiftsVector.addElement(rset.getString(1)+":"+rsetShifts.getString(1)+":"+status);

            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118129/sqlexception-this-resultset-is-closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) provides a clear explanation of this:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

So your options would be:

1. Use a different `Statement` instance for each query.
2. Collect all the results from each `ResultSet` (i.e. into a `Set` or a `List`) before moving on to the next one, and then run the comparison on the collected results instead of directly on the result-sets.

Comment: Thanks aroth... I used a different Statement instance and it worked perfectly...Awesome!!

Comment: @user1328181 - If aroth's answer helped you, You should mark it as an answer. That way it helps aroth and other people with the same problem will be able to see that there is a solution :)