# Groovy SQL Error - This ResultSet is closed

Tags: sql, postgresql, groovy

I am using Groovy's Sql object to perform queries on a postgres db. The queries are being executed as follows:

```
List<Map> results = sql.rows("select * from my_table")
List<Map> result2= sql.rows("select * from my_second_table")
```

I have a groovy method that performs two queries and then does some processing to loop through the data to make a different dataset, however, on some occasions I recieve a postgres exception `"This ResultSet is closed"` error.

having searched, I originally thought it might be to do with the issue here: [SQLException: This ResultSet is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118129/sqlexception-this-resultset-is-closed) (running multiple queries and trying to access the data from the resultsets after the fact) - however, we only seem to get the exception on quite high load - which suggests that it isnt as simple as the first dataset is closed on executing the second query as if this was the case I would expect it to happen consistently.

Can anyone shed any light on how Groovy's Sql object handles these situations or suggest what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Groovy SQL is kind of a weird cat.  Easy to use for simple stuff.  If you have more complex scenarios you probably are better off using something else.  IMHO

I first suggest doing one query, storing the results into a collection, do the second query and store the results in a collection and then do your operations between two collections rather than result sets.  If you data is too large for that, find some way to store the data locally before you start doing your aggregation or whatever.

If you don't like that, you might need to checkout the GDK source code to get a better idea what is done with the Sql.getInstance() related to result sets etc.  Then you can sidestep whatever land mine you are inadvertently stepping on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
List<Map> results = sql.rows("select * from my_table")
List<Map> result2= sql.rows("select * from my_second_table")
```

will not work even in plain Java (as already said in the answer you provided when second call is made on statement all resources dedicated during the previous call have to be released). As [mentioned by @Todd W Crone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505644/4672928) Groovy can optimize resources, e.g. release them dynamically or don't release them depending on certain run.

Actually I've tried with only one query. E.g. I've tried to get `ResultSet` and then iterate through it, like this (don't mind the names of table and field, query is rather simple; and result is one row that contains one column due to `LIMIT 1` clause):

```
def resultSet = sql.executeQuery("SELECT age FROM person WHERE id = 12345 LIMIT 1")
resultSet.next()
```

and got **This ResultSet is closed** error. Seems that Groovy optimizes resources and closes `ResultSet` immediately. I didn't look into the source code of Groovy SDK. I found that [eachRow](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#eachRow(groovy.lang.GString,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) and other methods with closure-style handlers work fine and don't throw **This ResultSet is closed** error.

Perhaps, methods with closure-style handlers can help you. For example, look at except from [the article where rows() method with closure is used](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.by/2011/09/groovy-goodness-access.html):

```
String query = 'select id as identifier, name as langName from languages'
def rows = db.rows(query, { meta ->
    assert meta.tableName == 'languages'
    assert meta.columnCount == 2
    // ...
})
```